# Why didn't the stolen Facebook access tokens give access to private messages?

Tags: facebook

Facebook discovered a "security issue" affecting 50 million accounts. Hackers were able to steal access tokens. But Facebook have said that,

> So far, our initial investigation has not shown that these tokens were
>   used to access any private messages or posts or to post anything to
>   these accounts.

How is this possible? If they have the access token, why can't they access private messages and posts?

Answer (score 1):

There is a very big difference between:

> has not shown that these tokens were used

and

> has shown that these tokens COULD not be used

The former implies a possibility, but they haven't done it.
The latter would imply that it would be impossible to do. Which isn't the case.

Comment: They claim a lack of evidence that something happened, which does not mean that the something in question did not happen.

Comment: No, but the way it is written, it implies that it hasn't been abused. Allthough I agree with what you say for the full 100%.